# nginx server blocks serving same site

Tags: nginx

I have 2 server blocks i.e. site1.conf and site2.conf, whose contents are as below respectively:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  site1.com;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/site1;
    index index.html index.htm;
}
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  site2.com;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/site2;
    index index.html index.htm;
}
```

Now, problem is that both of the domains go to site1, even if I go to domain site2.com, it serves content for site1. I have tried to do `service nginx reload` but still nothing.

Comment: if you remove the server block for `site1` and do a reload, what happens when trying to access `site2`?

Comment: If I mess up server block for site1, say I alter the name of the directory, navigating to site2 returns a 404. I don't get how they're related.

Comment: also try adding the following into each server block: `location / {try_files $uri $uri/ =404;}`

Comment: Check if you really go to `site2.com`, not `www.site2.com`. Or add `www.site2.com` to second block

Comment: Share the access log as well please.